# probability priority of comma and bar

Tags: probability, notation, bayesian

In probability does , have priority over |?

I am asking because of below question.

Is below X and (Y given by Z)?

P(X,Y|Z)

or is it (X and Y) given by Z?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question more directly, yes, comma (,) has higher priority than bar (|) when interpreting this notation.

So `P(X,Y|Z)` is the conditional probability of `X and Y` occurring together, given `Z`. It might help to think of this case as `P((X,Y)|Z)` (though such use of additional brackets is not common in the notation, afaik).

Similarly, `P(X|Y,Z)` is the conditional probability of `X`, given `Y and Z` (i.e. as if there were additional brackets as follows: `P(X|(Y,Z))`.

Answer (score 0):

The sign | denote the conditional **probability**. It is not an operation on the events. This sign does not refer to events, but to probability. And if $X,Y,Z$ are some events, then $P(X,Y \mid Z)$ is the conditional probability of the event $X\cap Y$, conditioning on the event $Z$.